# Issue setting up Odoo server on Windows

Tags: windows, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I have installed using both Odoo 10 and Odoo 11 and it gives me the same error 500 when connecting to the following address:

http://localhost:8069/

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error and
>   was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded
>   or there is an error in the application

This is the error in the log file:

```
2018-06-12 09:15:41,424 13968 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0-20180612
2018-06-12 09:15:41,424 13968 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo.conf
2018-06-12 09:15:41,426 13968 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: [u'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\OpenERP S.A.\\Odoo\\addons\\10.0', u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Odoo 10.0\\server\\odoo\\addons']
2018-06-12 09:15:41,426 13968 INFO ? odoo: database: thomas@localhost:5432
2018-06-12 09:15:41,456 13968 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Initiating shutdown
2018-06-12 09:15:41,456 13968 INFO ? odoo.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
2018-06-12 09:15:45,668 748 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0-20180612
2018-06-12 09:15:45,670 748 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo.conf
2018-06-12 09:15:45,671 748 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\OpenERP S.A.\\Odoo\\addons\\10.0', u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Odoo 10.0\\server\\odoo\\addons']
2018-06-12 09:15:45,671 748 INFO ? odoo: database: thomas@localhost:5432
2018-06-12 09:15:45,691 748 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on ACER-THOMAS:8069
2018-06-12 09:20:54,644 748 INFO ? odoo.addons.report.models.report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\thirdparty\wkhtmltopdf.exe
2018-06-12 09:20:55,512 748 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2018-06-12 09:20:57,529 748 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
2018-06-12 09:20:57,729 748 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2018 09:20:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2018-06-12 09:20:57,740 748 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi

  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 165, in execute

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 244, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 186, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 172, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1324, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1298, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 579, in __call__

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1462, in dispatch
    self.setup_db(httprequest)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1384, in setup_db
    httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1546, in db_monodb
    dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1514, in db_list
    dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 337, in list_dbs
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 635, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 177, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 518, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 586, in borrow
    **connection_info)
  File "psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect

OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Port 5432 is for PostgreSQL, that is fine.
I wonder why it cannot connect to localhost:8069.
Anyone has any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Obviously the postgres server is not running or not allowing any connections from Odoo. Without a database connection, Odoo won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot yes i realize it too and have uninstalled previous version of the database and reinstall everything with the postgrelsql that comes with the installation file.It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the file given below

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\postgresql.conf

The Version depends upon the PostgreSQL version you have installed

then find the line contains

```
listen_address = '*'
```

Please uncomment it.